# Why will Mongodb only use my index if I use hint

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, hint

I have a database with a ISODate() type field with an index (I also tried this experiment with string fields - same result).  I am using the open source version of MongoDB (4.x) and when I do a query / sort to find the max _finish_time, the index is not used unless I specify a hint.

My query is:

```
db.getCollection("test").find({}, { _finish_time: 1}).sort({_finish_time: -1}).limit(1)
```

which explains as:

```
{ 
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1.0, 
        "namespace" : "vdm-service-ts-staging.test", 
        "indexFilterSet" : false, 
        "parsedQuery" : {

        }, 
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
            "transformBy" : {
                "_finish_time" : 1.0
            }, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT", 
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "_finish_time" : -1.0
                }, 
                "limitAmount" : 1.0, 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", 
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN", 
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        "rejectedPlans" : [

        ]
    }, 
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "ip-10-82-245-45.us-west-2.compute.internal", 
        "port" : 27017.0, 
        "version" : "4.0.1", 
        "gitVersion" : "54f1582fc6eb01de4d4c42f26fc133e623f065fb"
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0, 
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1573220526, 1), 
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1573220526, 1), 
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0, "blIkiGcam87SDdbKeZKex/9JXBU="), 
            "keyId" : NumberLong(6715502669504446467)
        }
    }
}
```

Which scans the entire collection.  When I specify a hint for my available index, as in:

```
db.getCollection("test").find({}, { _finish_time: 1}).sort({_finish_time: -1}).limit(1).hint("_finish_time")
```

I get the query plan:

```
{ 
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1.0, 
        "namespace" : "vdm-service-ts-staging.test", 
        "indexFilterSet" : false, 
        "parsedQuery" : {

        }, 
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT", 
            "limitAmount" : 1.0, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
                "transformBy" : {
                    "_finish_time" : 1.0
                }, 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH", 
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "_finish_time" : -1.0
                        }, 
                        "indexName" : "_finish_time", 
                        "isMultiKey" : false, 
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "_finish_time" : [

                            ]
                        }, 
                        "isUnique" : false, 
                        "isSparse" : true, 
                        "isPartial" : false, 
                        "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                        "direction" : "forward", 
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "_finish_time" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        "rejectedPlans" : [

        ]
    }, 
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "ip-10-82-245-45.us-west-2.compute.internal", 
        "port" : 27017.0, 
        "version" : "4.0.1", 
        "gitVersion" : "54f1582fc6eb01de4d4c42f26fc133e623f065fb"
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0, 
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1573220603, 3), 
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1573220603, 3), 
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0, "qsGhD1DpI306XbqtNZDYVINPid8="), 
            "keyId" : NumberLong(6715502669504446467)
        }
    }
}
```

Which uses the index.  I would prefer not to have to add hint() to my queries and I am perplexed why it refuses to use the index.

My index is sparse and not unique.

I have tried other indexes and searching around, but I cannot find any reference to this problem in Stack overflow or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation of MongoDB

> If a sparse index would result in an incomplete result set for queries
>   and sort operations, MongoDB will not use that index unless a hint()
>   explicitly specifies the index.

To use the sparse index, explicitly specify the index with hint()

As hint() forces query optimizer to use index while performing execution of query

Comment: Well that totally explained my problem - but it was counter-intuitive.  If I added { _finish_time: {$exists: true} to my query then it did use the index.    It seems like they could still use the index for this query because of the sort - and limit - all of the records that lacked the field would be the same in the sort order. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3501690 A sparse index on  `_finish_time` won't include documents without the `_finish_time` field. The correctness issue preventing sparse index selection is that some documents matching your query filter of "all documents" would not be included using the sparse index.